# How to separate the joystick and screen slide when using the new input system in Unity？

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I am using unity's newInputSystem.My code run perfectly on PC,but it works badly on mobile phone. I am using "Primary Touch/Delta [Touchscreen]"[The camera rotate settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQPUx.png) to rotate the camera, and a "on-screen stick"[The script that provided by unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6Qr7.png) to move the character. It is just like a common TPS game's control method. However, when I move the stick, my camera rotate as well! How can I do?

Comment: in your camera rotation you just need to additionally check whether your touch is hovering the joystick ... customize it with a flag like `isUsingJoystick` which is enabled as long as you are touching it => in that case ignore the camera rotate action (or more advanced check for each touch index individually to allow both)